# Wait for User Input in Tkinter before continuing through the loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a bit of code in a loop that outputs 2 buttons and a label, but after that it continues, but I want it to not do anything until the user hits a button. If any of you know how to do that it would help a ton. I have no commands in it since I am not sure how I will do this.

"more" is if the user wants another Flashcard, with 1 being yes and 0 being no.
x is the flash card you are on.

```
while more == "1":
            if x <= 1:
                self.flashCardText = Label(self.flashcards, text = flashcard[x][y]).grid(row = 1, column = 2)
                self.flipButton = Button(self.flashcards, text = "Flip", command = lambda: flip()).grid(row = 2, column = 1)
                self.nextButton = Button(self.flashcards, text = "Next", command = lambda: x += 1).grid(row = 2, column = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are creating lots of buttons in a while loop. So you can do it like that. What you can do, is to create some sort of dialog (example below). Can't say much without full code of yours, but the example below should be useful:

```
from tkinter import *

top = Tk()

class Test(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.x = 0

        flashCardText = Label(self, text = print('flashcard')).grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        flipButton = Button(self, text = "Flip", command = lambda: print('flip')).grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        nextButton = Button(self, text = "Next", command = self._test_output).grid(row = 2, column = 3)

        self.grid()

    def _test_output(self):

        if self.x < 2:
            print("increasing x")
            self.x +=1
        else:
            print("x is 2")
            self.master.destroy()




t = Test(top)


top.mainloop()
```

So basically, in this example the Test window is being showed until `self.x` gets to 2. 'self.x' is being increased with each press of **Next** button. In this example other buttons don't do much.